How to delay registeration into nacos when using spring boot
I am using spring boot(3.3.1) to develop a web application and I am using nacos 2.x as the register center. I am facing an issue where the spring boot rolling application update in kubernetes fails when the new kubernete pod is created. I think spring boot is not ready to recieve requests after registeration into nacos. So, I want the spring boot application to delay some seconds(20s+) before registering into nacos. Is it possible? I have found the following parameter:
-Dcom.alibaba.nacos.naming.delay.register=true

but this was not mentioned on nacos official documentation.

I'm not sure about nacos directly, but you might be able to create a bean for it and delay its initialization, there are a few options, postConstruct+sleep, using ApplicationReadyEvent + onApplicationEvent, using @scheduled plus a desired fixed delay and long max value as interval

If the nacos support delay registeration, it will be simple and reliable. or I have to disable the auto registation and registered in application events by myself.
